# Heat equation on a three dimensional box

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the heat equation on a three dimensional box with

$0 < x < L$, $0 < y < H$ and $0 < z < W$.

The heat equation is given by

$$u_t=k(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}).$$

and the initial temperature distribution is given by $$u(0,x,y,z)=f(x,y,z).$$

Solve the heat equation using separation of variables assuming the following boundary conditions:

- $u(t,0,y,z)=0$
- $u_y(t,x,0,z)=0$
- $u_z(t,x,y,0)=0$
- $u(t,L,y,z)=0$
- $u_y(t,x,H,z)=0$
- $u(t,x,y,W)=0$

Im not sure how to solve with the multiple variables.

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables means you assume that $u(t,x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)T(t)$.
Under this assumption your heat equation becomes
$$XYZT^\prime = k(X^{\prime\prime}YZT+XY^{\prime\prime}ZT+XYZ^{\prime\prime}T),$$
where I've dropped the variables $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ for notational convenience.
If we now divide both sides by $XYZT$, we get the following:
$$\frac{T^\prime}{T} = k\left(\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}+\frac{Y^{\prime\prime}}{Y}+\frac{Z^{\prime\prime}}{Z}\right)$$
and we note that the left side is independent of $x$, $y$ and $z$, whereas the right side is independent of $t$. Hence both sides are in fact constant and we get the following equations:

- $X^{\prime\prime} = a_x X$
- $Y^{\prime\prime} = a_y Y$
- $Z^{\prime\prime} = a_z Z$
- $T^{\prime} = k(a_x+a_y+a_z) T$

Where $a_x$, $a_y$ and $a_z$ are arbitrary real numbers.
Now you just have to find the solutions to the above equations that fulfil your boundary conditions.